# "Unable to read server configuration" RealVNC setup

Tags: 20.10

I was following these [instructions](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/realvnc-install-on-rpi4-with-ubuntumate-20-04-1-lts/22559/2) as closely as possible, when at the very end, after signing into RealVNC , I would click "[Apply](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTbf2.jpg)" to confirm changes and it would fail.

The RealVNC window tells me that it "Failed to read configuration" while my terminal window reads

```
   /usr/bin/vncserver-x11-core: error while loading shared libraries: /lib/libbcm_host.so: invalid ELF header
<11> 2021-02-15T02:12:32.927Z TvBox-desktop vnclicensewiz_helper[10457]: ProcHelper: Unable to read server configuration: read: Connection reset by peer (104)
```

I'll be honest, I have no clue what I am doing so I am pretty sure it's something obvious. I am running Ubuntu 20.10 on a Raspberry Pi 3B+ (I'm aware that isn't ideal, I'll be upgrading to the RPi4 down the line). I just now realized the instructions I followed were for Ubuntu Mate. Would that make a difference? Regardless, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.